# Unicode characters display incorrectly in JSP

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, unicode

I have a SpringMVC application with a few JSP files. I've been trying to add Vietnamese characters into the JSP files, but all the characters always turned into gibberish. Things I've tried:

Adding this tag

```
<%@page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
```

And this one

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Writing custom encoding filter

```
public class EncodingFilter implements Filter {

    private String encoding = "UTF-8";

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest,
                         ServletResponse servletResponse,
                         FilterChain filterChain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        servletRequest.setCharacterEncoding(encoding);
        servletResponse.setCharacterEncoding(encoding);
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        String encodingParam = filterConfig.getInitParameter("encoding");
        if (encodingParam != null) {
            encoding = encodingParam;
        }
    }

    public void destroy() {

    }
}
```

Using CharacterEncodingFilter:

```
@Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
        CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
        characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        return new Filter[] { characterEncodingFilter, new EncodingFilter() };
    }
```

So far, none of these works, and I do have the correct font. I've tried editing directly on the browser and the characters are displayed correctly. I've also set my IDE to UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: *"I've also set my IDE to UTF-8 encoding."* Based on the information provided so far, this was not done correctly. You'd better tell about the IDE used and how exactly you ensured that JSP files are saved using UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: @BalusC I use Intellij Idea, there is a setting option for file encoding. I've saved the jsp files with Intellij and tried opening them with Atom, the texts were still correct.

Comment: Then `pageEncoding` is not done/interpreted correctly in some way. Did you ensure you placed it in all JSPs in case you're using includes? How does the `content-type` response header look like?

Comment: Yes, I did include all the necessary templates. The response header contains  "Content-Type →text/html;charset=UTF-8"